# Split a row into multiple rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split a record in a table to 2 records based on a column value. The input table displays the 3 types of products and their price. For a specific product (row) only its corresponding column has value. The other columns have Null.

My requirement is - whenever the product column value (in a row) is composite (i.e. has more than one product, e.g. Bolt + Brush), the record must be split into two rows  - 1 row each for the composite product types.

So, in this example, notice how the 2nd row (in the input) gets split into 2 rows -> 1 row for "Bolt" and another for the "Brush", with their price extracted from their corresponding columns (i.e in this case, "Bolt" = $3.99 and "Brush" = $6.99)

Note: For composite product values there can be at most 2 products as shown in this example (e.g. Bolt + Brush)

```
CustId | Product        | Hammer | Bolt  | Brush
--------------------------------
12345  | Hammer         | $5.99  | Null  | Null  
53762  | **Bolt+Brush** | Null   | $3.99 | $4.99  
43883  | Brush          | Null   | Null  | $4.99
```

I have tried creating 2 predetermined records via UNION ALL using a CTE and then main_table Left Outer Join with CTE, so that the join yields 2 records instead.

```
#CustId   | Product   | Price  #
12345     | Hammer    | $5.99  
**53762** | **Bolt**  | $3.99  
**53762** | **Brush** | $4.99  
43883     | Brush     | $4.99
```

This has to be solved by Spark-SQL only.

Comment: Is it the case where the various Price columns will only-and-ever have a non-null value if the related product is in the Product column?  If so, you might be able to devise an 3-stage UNION statement; one stage where column HAMMER is not null, one where column BOLT is not null, and one where column BRUSH is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
select CustId, 'Hammer' as product, Hammer
from t
where Product like '%Hammer%'
union all
select CustId, 'Bolt' as product, Bolt
from t
where Product like '%Bolt%'
union all
select CustId, 'Brush' as product, Brush
from t
where Product like '%Brush%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work also

```
select custid, product, 
            case when product like '%Hammer%' then hammer 
                 when product like '%Bolt%'   then bolt 
            else brush end as Price from
(select custid, explode(split(product,'\\+')) as product,  hammer, bolt, brush  
from t) x;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly